# Error when attempting to print a file and the size of that file together

Tags: python

I'd like to start off any say that I am new to coding in general, so my knowledge is very limited.

I am currently trying to write a python script that takes the input of a directory and then writes the files and directories to the screen with the size of each file.

So far my code is:

```
import os
import sys
import string

path = raw_input('Please enter the directory: ')

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
     for rt in root:
             print os.path.join(root)
     for directory in directories:
             print os.path.join(directory)
     for filename in filenames: 
             directory = directories
             full_file = os.path.join(directory, filename)
             size = os.path.getsize(full_file)
             print os.path.join(directory, filename)+(' >> ')+str(size)
```

One of the issues I'm running into is when I try to print the filename and size of the file together I get the error message:

```
"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list".
```

I am aware that I can only concatenate a list to list or string to string, but I am stuck on how I would fix this to get the output I want.

Suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing uses of `+` to `,`

Comment: `directory = directories` doesn't look right to me. What are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: @Kevin When attempting to join directory and filename together with `os.path.join` I would get the error that `directory` was not defined. That was my poor attempt at removing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
import os

path = raw_input('Please enter the directory: ')
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
     for filename in filenames:
             full_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
             size = os.path.getsize(full_path)
             print full_path + ' >> ' + str(size)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can see where I went wrong in my program now.